# Request parameters not recognised by DropletInvoker.invokeDroplet

Tags: java, atg, atg-dust, atg-droplet

I'm trying to invoke RQLQueryForEach droplet from using DUST's DropletInvoker by using below code.

```
HeadPipelineServlet dynamoHandler = (HeadPipelineServlet) Nucleus.getGlobalNucleus().resolveName("/atg/dynamo/servlet/dafpipeline/DynamoHandler");
DynamoHttpServletRequest request = dynamoHandler.getRequest(null); 

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
TestingDynamoHttpServletRequest wrappedRequest = new TestingDynamoHttpServletRequest(request, buffer);
TestingDynamoHttpServletResponse wrappedResponce = new TestingDynamoHttpServletResponse(request.getResponse());

DynamoServlet droplet = (DynamoServlet) wrappedRequest.resolveName("/atg/dynamo/droplet/RQLQueryForEach");

wrappedRequest.setParameter("repository", "/atg/userprofiling/ProfileAdapterRepository");
wrappedRequest.setParameter("itemDescriptor", "user");
wrappedRequest.setParameter("transactionManager", "/atg/dynamo/transaction/TransactionManager");
wrappedRequest.setParameter("queryRQL", "ALL");

DropletInvoker mDropletInvoker = new DropletInvoker(Nucleus.getGlobalNucleus());
DropletResult result = mDropletInvoker.invokeDroplet(droplet, null, wrappedRequest, wrappedResponce);

assertNotNull("Check that output got rendered",result.getRenderedOutputParameter("output"));
```

invokeDroplet method is failing with exception "javax.servlet.ServletException: required parameter 'repository' not passed to droplet." Can any one point me in the right direction, what is that I'm doing incorrectly?

Here is the full stack trace...

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: required parameter 'repository' not passed to droplet
    at atg.repository.servlet.RQLQueryForEach.getRangeResults(RQLQueryForEach.java:254)
    at atg.repository.servlet.RQLQueryForEach.getResults(RQLQueryForEach.java:220)
    at atg.repository.servlet.RQLQueryForEach.service(RQLQueryForEach.java:179)
    at atg.servlet.DynamoServlet.service(DynamoServlet.java:152)
```

I could solve the problem using additional parameters. However the i still couldn't figure out why my original code isn't working.

**Workaround I found**

```
HeadPipelineServlet dynamoHandler = (HeadPipelineServlet) Nucleus.getGlobalNucleus().resolveName("/atg/dynamo/servlet/dafpipeline/DynamoHandler");
Map<String,Object> additionalParams = new HashMap<>();
additionalParams.put("repository", "/atg/userprofiling/ProfileAdapterRepository");
additionalParams.put("itemDescriptor", "user");
additionalParams.put("queryRQL", "ALL");
DropletInvoker mDropletInvoker = new DropletInvoker(Nucleus.getGlobalNucleus());
DropletResult result = mDropletInvoker.invokeDroplet("/atg/dynamo/droplet/RQLQueryForEach",additionalParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you building your dust code properly? The error only suggests that the input parameter `repository` is not sent in the request.

Was there a point when the below line was not in your code. If you have added it, probably your changes have not been built. Could you clean your project and try again. Other than this I don't see any thing wrong with your code. Also if you are using eclipse, probably your **Build Automatically** under Projects menu is not checked.

```
wrappedRequest.setParameter("repository", "/atg/userprofiling/ProfileAdapterRepository");
```

Comment: Nope building wasn't the problem. I even wrote a sysout after this setParameter and did a getParameter which resulted in printing the repository value I have put in. So, the code is getting built.

Comment: OK, could you try using `ServletTestUtil.createDynamoRequest(params,buffer,method)`
as explained http://atgdust.sourceforge.net/servlet-test.html

Probably the way you are setting the parameters is not the correct one.

Comment: It is possible that my way may not be right. I will read the page and give that a shot. However, I found a workaround of passing the parameters using additionalParameters attribute of invokeDroplet.